# Laravel: Check if MySQL query has result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

First Laravel project. I have a controllerfunction what checks if there any record with that barcode. If no insert a record. If yes add one for the count.

```
public function sellmode(Request $request){
    $barcode=$request->barcode;
    $test = DB::select('select count from sellmode where barcode = ?', [$barcode]);
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($test);
    if ($row_cnt == 0) {
        Debugbar::info('Új sor');
        DB::insert('insert into sellmode (barcode, count) VALUES (?, ?)', [$barcode, '1']); 
    } else {
        Debugbar::info('Meglévő frissítése');
        DB::update('update sellmode set count = count + 1 WHERE barcode = ?' [$barcode]);
    }
    return view(sell);
```

}

When I tried it, it had the following error:

> ErrorException in SellController.php line 17: mysqli_num_rows()
>   expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given

What did I wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `mysqli_num_rows` or any mysqli related functions here. Laravel uses PDO. Though for argument's sake, if you want to see how many rows were returned, you can just count the number of values in the resulting array... `$row_cnt = count($test);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't just just `mysql_num_rows` on a Laravel query builder. Laravel query builder will return a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections), so you can just use the [`isEmpty`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-isempty) function to find out if it has any results.

```
if ($test->isEmpty()) {
    Debugbar::info('Új sor');
    DB::insert('insert into sellmode (barcode, count) VALUES (?, ?)', [$barcode, '1']); 
} else {
    Debugbar::info('Meglévő frissítése');
    DB::update('update sellmode set count = count + 1 WHERE barcode = ?' [$barcode]);
}
```

If you are using a Laravel version pre-5.3, the query builder will return an array. In this case, you can use the php [`count`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function on this array to know how many rows are returned

```
if (count($test) === 0) {
    Debugbar::info('Új sor');
    DB::insert('insert into sellmode (barcode, count) VALUES (?, ?)', [$barcode, '1']); 
} else {
    Debugbar::info('Meglévő frissítése');
    DB::update('update sellmode set count = count + 1 WHERE barcode = ?' [$barcode]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got an another error: "FatalThrowableError in SellController.php line 17: Call to a member function isEmpty() on array"

Comment: In this case you are probably using a Laravel version lower than 5.3. I have updated my answer with a solution for these versions.

Comment: I thought, that I using 5.3, but now I ran 'php artisan --version' and the output was 'Laravel Framework 5.4.13'. I tried the second command, too, the "New row" is working, but the "Update"'s ouput is this errormessage: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'o' at line 1 (SQL: o)

Answer (score 2):

It would be a good idea to create a model and use that to query the db. Maybe something like this (in my opinion it is way easier):

```
$sellMode = SellMode::where('barcode', $barcode)->get();
if($sellMode->isEmpty()){
   Debugbar::info('Új sor');
   $sellMode = SellMode::create(['barcode' => $barcode, 'count' => 1]);
}
else{
    Debugbar::info('Meglévő frissítése');
    $sellMode->increment('count');
}
```

Comment: Don't know which version you are using, but take a look at the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent

Answer (score 2):

When I used `test->isEmpty()` or `count($test) == 0` I still kept getting this error:

> Undefined offset: 0

So I ended up using this to check for an empty return value from DB::select:

```
$test = DB::select('select count from sellmode where barcode = ?', [$barcode]);

if(collect($test)->first()) {
    // ...
} else {
    $response = new \stdClass();
    $response->error = true;
    $response->message = 'Sellmode not found';
    return response(json_encode($response))->header('Content-Type','application/json');                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three elegant Laravel collection methods are isEmpty(), count() and first(). Count no longer needs to be used with vanillaPHP in Laravel.

```
$result = Model::all();
// if your resultset has something
if ($result->isEmpty()) // return false
if ($result->count() > 0) // return false
if ($result->first()) // return model object

// if your resultset has no entries
if ($result->isEmpty()) // return true
if ($result->count() > 0) // return true
if ($result->first()) // return null
```